# Как передать значение из реестра

Tags: c++, qt, ui, settings

У меня есть виджет строкового поля. Как сделать, чтобы сохранялся текст этой строки и передавался в реестр, чтобы потом можно было загрузить сохранённый текст данной строки.

**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSettings>
#include "counter2.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow* ui;
    counter2*       counter_2;
    counter2*       counter_3;
    QSettings*      settings;

public:
    void save();
    void load();


//signals:
//    void toggleToCounter2();

private slots:
        //Diclaration slots'
    void cleanLines();
    void cleanAmounters();
    void cleanAll();

    void toggleCounter3();
    void toggleCounter4();
    void toggleCounter5();
    void toggleCounter6();
    void toggleWindow2();
    void toggleWindow3();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "counter2.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    counter_2 = new counter2();
    counter_3 = new counter2();
    settings = new QSettings("SimpleStudio", "Counter", this);

    //Diclaration variables & QObject::connect

    connect(counter_2, &counter2::toggleToCounter1,
            this,      &MainWindow::show);

    connect(counter_3, &counter2::toggleToCounter1,
            this,      &MainWindow::show);

    connect(counter_2, &counter2::toggleToCounter3,
            this,      &MainWindow::toggleWindow3);

    QObject::connect(ui->toggleButton2, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                      this,     SLOT(toggleWindow2()));

    QObject::connect(ui->toggleButton3, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                      this,     SLOT(toggleWindow3()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanLines, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,           SLOT(cleanLines()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanAmounts, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,             SLOT(cleanAmounters()));

    QObject::connect(ui->cleanAll, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,         SLOT(cleanAll()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox3, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter3()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox4, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter4()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox5, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter5()));

    QObject::connect(ui->checkBox6, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this,          SLOT(toggleCounter6()));

//    load();
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    save();
}
//Discription slots'
void MainWindow::save() {

    ui->nameCounter1->setText(settings->setValue("nameString1", ui->nameCounter1->text()));
}

void MainWindow::load() {

    ui->nameCounter1->setText(settings->value("nameString1").toString());
}

void MainWindow::cleanLines() {

    ui->nameCounter1->clear();
    ui->nameCounter2->clear();
    ui->nameCounter3->clear();
    ui->nameCounter4->clear();
    ui->nameCounter5->clear();
    ui->nameCounter6->clear();

}

void MainWindow::cleanAmounters() {

    ui->amounter1->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter2->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter3->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter4->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter5->setValue(0);
    ui->amounter6->setValue(0);

}

void MainWindow::cleanAll() {

    ui->nameCounterTop->clear();

    ui->checkBox3->setChecked(0);
    emit MainWindow::toggleCounter3();

    ui->checkBox4->setChecked(0);
    emit MainWindow::toggleCounter4();

    ui->checkBox5->setChecked(0);
    emit MainWindow::toggleCounter5();

    ui->checkBox6->setChecked(0);
    emit MainWindow::toggleCounter6();

    emit MainWindow::cleanLines();
    emit MainWindow::cleanAmounters();
}

void MainWindow::toggleCounter3(){

    if(!ui->checkBox3->isChecked()) {

        ui->amounter3->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter3->setEnabled(0);

    } else {

        ui->amounter3->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter3->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void MainWindow::toggleCounter4(){

    if(!ui->checkBox4->isChecked()) {

        ui->amounter4->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter4->setEnabled(0);

    } else {

        ui->amounter4->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter4->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void MainWindow::toggleCounter5(){

    if(!ui->checkBox5->isChecked()) {
        ui->amounter5->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter5->setEnabled(0);

    } else {
        ui->amounter5->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter5->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void MainWindow::toggleCounter6(){

    if(!ui->checkBox6->isChecked()) {
        ui->amounter6->setEnabled(0);
        ui->nameCounter6->setEnabled(0);

    } else {
        ui->amounter6->setEnabled(1);
        ui->nameCounter6->setEnabled(1);
    }
}

void MainWindow::toggleWindow2() {
        counter_2->show();
        this->close();
}

void MainWindow::toggleWindow3() {
        counter_3->show();

        this->close();

}

//void counter2::toggleWindow3() {
//    counter_2->close();
//    counter_3->show();
//}
```

Ошибка: mainwindow.cpp:64: ошибка: reference to type 'const QString' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'void'

Comment: В методе `void MainWindow::save()` вы вызываете `setValue()`, а затем пытаетесь результат работы этой функции (которого нет), записать в текстовое поле. Оставьте в том методе только `settings->setValue("nameString1", ui->nameCounter1->text())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Qt за работу с реестром отвечает класс `QSettings`:

```
// Открываем ключ реестра (как бы папку).
// Если компилятор выдаёт ошибку на строку ниже, замените Registry32Format
// на RegistryFormat.
QSettings reg("путь до ключа", QSettings::Registry32Format);

// Записываем значение текстового поля linewidget в реестр
reg.setValue("имя значения", linewidget.value());

// Читаем значение из реестра в текстовое поле linewidget 
linewidget.setValue(reg.getValue("имя значения").toString());
```

Вообще, он может работать не только с реестром, но и с файлами конфигурации, но в данном случае мы направляем его именно на реестр.

Comment: вот чтение из реестра ui->nameCounter1->setText(settings->setValue("nameString1", ui->nameCounter1->text())); компилятор пишет: " Counter\mainwindow.cpp:65: ошибка: reference to type 'const QString' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'void' "

Comment: В методе `void MainWindow::save()` вы вызываете `setValue()`, а затем пытаетесь результат работы этой функции (которого нет), записать в текстовое поле. Оставьте в том методе только `settings->setValue("nameString1", ui->nameCounter1->text())`.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>У Вас даже тег [settings](/questions/tagged/settings) стоит, надо было это же слово в документации Qt вбить.</sub>

Вам нужен класс [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsettings.html), в Windows он как раз с реестром работает. Там же по ссылке есть пример работы с этим классом.

Comment: я знаю, что работать надо с QSetting, дело в том как передать значения

Comment: @Pon4iPay, тогда приводите в код в вопросе и показывайте, что не получается.

Comment: внёс весь код, ошибка ниже

Comment: Ответы, думаю, стоит удалить — телепатия не сработала, мы попытались решить не ту проблему. К тому же стоит проголосовать за закрытие как опечатки (см. мой комментарий к вопросу).

Comment: а как тогда проголосовать? И лучше тогда сделайте свой комментарий  ответом и я учту его как решение

Comment: @Arhad, лучше восстановите свой ответ и впишите туда же комментарий. На такой вопрос из поисковика легко попасть, а тут и ответы будут общие.

Comment: @ixSci, сделано.